# Exporting Data into a form type format from Microsoft Access query to Microsoft Excel Worksheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, microsoft-access-2007

I have a query which holds information for products that need user input for one attribute. The users are not comfortable with Access so the data needs to appear in Excel for them.

Each month, I have a list of say 50 products, each product needs to have its own worksheet as they go to different marketing managers to complete the attribute.

Once they complete the information, it needs to get loaded back into the Access database. I know there must be a method in MS Office, but I don't know how to do it.

I would prefer not to use VBA if possible, but will, if necessary.  I have MS Office 2007.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the attach table command (in the external data source tab, choose Excel and the last option "attach table"). As long as your excel table stays at the same location, anytime you open access your table in the database will sync. You'll have to do the set up once for each tab in Excel though.